# Customization of liferay sample site

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am new to liferay.
I am using Liferay 6.1.1 CE.

I got a sample site and I have few doubts:

1. What is the difference between public pages and private pages in liferay?
2. How to use it? Lots of users in mysite. So everyone have the common public and private pages? How can I customize it?

I have already gone through the documentation in Liferay site.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well it doesn't seem you have gone through the documentation, atleast not through the wonderful [Liferay 6.1 User Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide)

Comment: This is simple. If you want to restrict the pages (authentication required) create private pages. Public pages are accessible without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the [Web-Content Management](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/using-liferay-web-content-management) section of the [Liferay 6.1 User Guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide), to understand Sites.

Then you can also go through [Personalization and Customization](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/drools) section, to understand User public and private pages. Also how are they different from normal Site public and private pages.

Going through the User guide is a must for every Liferay developer, the information is nicely collated at once place and also the sections are categorized very nicely.

Now to answer your questions in short:

> What is the difference between public pages and private pages in liferay?

There are two types: Site Pages (Public & Private) and User pages (Public and Private)

- **Site Pages:** Public pages of a Site (or Community as previously called) are those pages which can be accessed by any User irrespective of the User being a member of the Site. While Private pages are those pages which can be accessed only by those User who are member of the Site or are Omni-Admins (Super administrator).

  - Site Public pages can be understood as the reception area of an Office, anybody can enter for inquiry or to drool over the receptionist (*ahem ahem*) :-).
  - Site Private pages can be understood as the actual area where people work, ofcourse the area where only employees are allowed.
- **User Pages (or User Personal Sites):** Now User Public pages can be accessed by anybody but User Private Pages can be accessed only by the User.

  - Public pages can be understood as your house's veranda where anybody can come to meet you.
  - Private pages can be understood as the rooms in your home where only members of the family can come (well it depends upon you who you want inside as you are the Omni-Admin :-) )

> How to Use It?

There are various ways to use these depending upon your requirement. Also I would suggest to play around the <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> --> <kbd>Sites</kbd> --> <kbd>Manage Pages</kbd>

> So everyone have the common public and private pages? How can I customize it?

If you want that every User should see different content in their pages then you are talking about User public pages. Also you should go through the [Management](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/administering-liferay-portal) section of the User Guide to understand User Management and also about User-groups and what role usergroups play in User Personal Sites.

Customizations also depend on Portlets, as to how are they made to show different content depending upon the user who is accessing it or depending upon the Site in which they are added.

Customizations of look-and-feel of the Pages or the whole sites can also be done using [Themes](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7).

Hope this helps in understand liferay better.

Comment: ..Thanks for your valuable reply..

Comment: How can i disable add,manage and edit control of a user's "My Public Pages"?

Comment: There are different ways. It would be better to ask this as a new question rather than having a conversation in the comments section. That way you might get more responses and also votes :-). Thank you